Magento in Kubernetes and Docker not working
I'm trying to deploy Magento2 application in Kubernetes. This is how my Dockerfile looks like.
FROM php:8.1-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    nginx \
    zip \
    unzip \
    git \
    curl \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libonig-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    libxslt-dev \
    libicu-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql pdo mbstring exif pcntl bcmath gd intl soap xsl zip sockets

RUN echo "memory_limit=512M" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/memory-limit.ini

WORKDIR /var/www/html

COPY . /var/www/html

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer


ARG COMPOSER_AUTH
RUN echo "$COMPOSER_AUTH" > /var/www/html/auth.json

RUN composer install

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html

RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html/var/cache \
    /var/www/html/var/log \
    /var/www/html/var/page_cache \
    /var/www/html/var/view_preprocessed \
    && chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/var \
    && chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/var/cache \
    && chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/var/log \
    && chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/var/page_cache \
    && chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/var/view_preprocessed


RUN rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

EXPOSE 80


CMD ["sh", "-c", "php bin/magento setup:install --base-url=${BASE_URL} --db-host=${DB_HOST} --db-name=${DB_NAME} --db-user=${DB_USER} --db-password=${DB_PASSWORD} --admin-firstname=${ADMIN_FIRSTNAME} --admin-lastname=${ADMIN_LASTNAME} --admin-email=${ADMIN_EMAIL} --admin-user=${ADMIN_USER} --admin-password=${ADMIN_PASSWORD} --language=${LANGUAGE} --currency=${CURRENCY} --timezone=${TIMEZONE} --use-rewrites=${USE_REWRITES} --elasticsearch-host=${ELASTICSEARCH_HOST} --elasticsearch-port=${ELASTICSEARCH_PORT} && php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer && service nginx start && php-fpm"]

And I'm passing the magento command variables via Kubernetes deployment. In the Kubernetes pod logs I see below.

[Progress: 1577 / 1583]
│ │ Enabling caches:
│ │ Current status:
│ │ layout: 1
│ │ block_html: 1
│ │ full_page: 1
│ │ [Progress: 1578 / 1583]
│ │ Installing admin user...
│ │ [Progress: 1579 / 1583]
│ │ Caches clearing:
│ │ Cache cleared successfully
│ │ [Progress: 1580 / 1583]
│ │ Disabling Maintenance Mode:
│ │ [Progress: 1581 / 1583]
│ │ Post installation file permissions check...
│ │ For security, remove write permissions from these directories:
'/var/www/html/app/etc'
│ │ [Progress: 1582 / 1583]
│ │ Write installation date...
│ │ [Progress: 1583 / 1583]
│ │ [SUCCESS]: Magento installation complete.
│ │ [SUCCESS]: Magento Admin URI: /admin_vfrrpn
│ │ Nothing to import.
│ │ Enabled developer mode.
│ │ Starting nginx: nginx.
│ │ [03-Oct-2024 19:11:00] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 36
│ │ [03-Oct-2024 19:11:00] NOTICE: ready to handle connections

And this is my nginx.conf
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my-url;

    root /var/www/html/pub;

    index index.php index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000; # Ensure this matches the PHP-FPM configuration
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_index index.php;

        # Increase buffer sizes for large headers
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        proxy_buffer_size 128k;
        proxy_buffers 4 256k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}

But when I access https://my-url//admin_vfrrpn it shows below error message.

UnexpectedValueException: The stream or file
"/var/www/html//var/log/system.log" could not be opened in append
mode: Failed to open stream: Permission denied The exception occurred
while attempting to log: The stream or file
"/var/www/html//var/log/system.log" could not be opened in append
mode: Failed to open stream: Permission denied The exception occurred
while attempting to log: Reference to undeclared plugin with name
'outOfStockSorting'. in
/var/www/html/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:146
Stack trace:

I then tried these commands
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/var && \
chmod -R 775 /var/www/html/var && \
find /var/www/html/var -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \; && \
find /var/www/html/var -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;

And now I get 502 Bad Gateway when I try to access my url
